# Are there any simulators for esp32 that support WiFi?

Tags: esp32

- https://github.com/Ebiroll/qemu_esp32
- https://github.com/espressif/qemu

Most popular esp32 simulators seem to have the above.
By the way I need a physical WiFi connection.
Are there any simulators for esp32 that support WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "I need a physical WiFi connection"? Software running on an emulator is abstracted from the physical network connections of the host machine. If you connect your host machine to a WiFi network then the emulator will use this WiFi to communicate. There are specific instructions in the README of the project you linked.

Comment: Which part of the readme are you referring to? What I want is to send WiFi Raw Payload.

Comment: I was referring to https://github.com/Ebiroll/qemu_esp32#networking-support but it refers to networking, not raw WiFi payload. Would be much clearer if you said so in the question.